# Multiprocessing : NULL result without error in PyObject_Call

Tags: python, numpy, multidimensional-array, queue, multiprocessing

Here is a sample program where I use multiprocessing. The calculations are done with `multiprocessing.Process` and the results are collected using `multiprocessing.Queue`.

```
#THIS PROGRAM RUNS WITH ~40Gb RAM. (you can reduce a,b,c for less RAM 
#but then it works for smaller values)
#PROBLEM OCCURS ONLY FOR HUGE DATA.   
from numpy import *
import multiprocessing as mp

a = arange(0, 3500, 5)
b = arange(0, 3500, 5)
c = arange(0, 3500, 5)  
a0 = 540. #random values
b0 = 26.
c0 = 826.
def rand_function(a, b, c, a0, b0, c0):
    Nloop = 100.
    def loop(Nloop, out):
        res_total = zeros((700, 700, 700), dtype = 'float') 
        n = 1
        while n <= Nloop:
            rad = sqrt((a-a0)**2 + (b-b0)**2 + (c-c0)**2)
            res_total += rad
            n +=1 
        out.put(res_total)
    out = mp.Queue() 
    jobs = []
    Nprocs = mp.cpu_count()
    print "No. of processors : ", Nprocs
    for i in range(Nprocs):
        p = mp.Process(target = loop, args=(Nloop/Nprocs, out)) 
        jobs.append(p)
        p.start()

    final_result = zeros((700, 700, 700), dtype = 'float')

    for i in range(Nprocs):
        final_result = final_result + out.get()

    p.join()
test = rand_function(a,b,c,a0, b0, c0)
```

Here is the error message :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/multiprocessing/queues.py", line 266, in _feed
    send(obj)
SystemError: NULL result without error in PyObject_Call
```

I read [here](http://bugs.python.org/issue17560) that it is a bug. But I am unable to understand.
Can anyone please tell me any way out to calculate huge data using multiprocessing?

Thank you very much

Answer (score 4):

The bug report your reference states that multiprocessing module is unable to push huge arguments to subprocess.

The reason is that it needs to pickle these arguments and store the pickled blob somewhere in memory.

You, however, don't need to pass arrays as arguments.

Possible causes:

- passing a closure `loop` as a target
- passing `mp.Queue()` as argument

Please see http://stevenengelhardt.com/2013/01/16/python-multiprocessing-module-and-closures/ about converting your closure to a class.

Set up full state before you give control to multiprocessing.

Comment: The problem is OP tries to put a 2.56 GB Numpy array through the `multiprcessing.Queue`. This is still a relatively huge amount and can run out of memory or be unsupported by the pickle module.

Comment: Python 3 fixes some problems with large pickles, so you might give that a try if you can.