# Multiprocessing memory limitation

Tags: python, memory, multiprocessing, shared-memory

Can anyone please shed some light into what's the highest memory which can be reached from `multiprocessing`? 
I am running into an issue where `multiprocessing.Queue` fails by returning the following error when I run a program with arrays of size ~ 40 Gb. The same program works for the smaller arrays:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/multiprocessing/queues.py", line 266, in _feed
    send(obj)
SystemError: NULL result without error in PyObject_Call
```

So can anyone please share some information regarding the limitations for huge data?

Thank you

Comment: Have you monitored your computer's memory usage during that program run? What did you observe?

Comment: Yes I have 64Gb RAM and when I give huge data like arrays of dimension 1000**3 it gives the above error, but works fine for smaller arrays. You can find an example here [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22656285/multiprocessing-null-result-without-error-in-pyobject-call)

Comment: An array with size 40GB? That's just too big. Objects sent through `Queue` will be serialized and deserialized, and during that process the memory usage will double, taking at least 80GB.

Comment: Okay, it doesn't work for 20Gb data either. Could you please show me any information regarding what is too big?

Comment: Why not just do a brute force grid search to find out when too much is too much?

Comment: Yes, I know it works for arrays of size 10 Gb but doesn't for 20 Gb. But I am not sure if such a limit exists or if there is a way out?

Comment: I would suggest you to observe the system's overall memory usage during your program runtime. If it's at 100% and then fails, it's probably due to insufficient memory. If it's significantly below that value, it may be a limitation imposed by one of the involved software modules.